# iframe cross domain dom handeling

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, browser

I am loading `abc.com` web site in `xyz.com` website through `iframe`. It is working fine.I have a link in `abc.com`. when I click that link, I want to change the `xyz.com` text. Can you suggest me how can I achieve this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: sounds like cross domain, and iFrames are subject to the same origin policy as well.

Comment: @vico — "You can't directly access frames across origins" is the first sentence of my answer there! (Ajax wouldn't work because it has its own set of cross origin issues).

Comment: o ok i didn't look at the details i guess it is a suitable solution. (comment removed)